# How to check for specific object key and update if exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have text inputs that are writing to a model. I want those objects to write to the model and update if the key exists.

For example: If I submit,

```
Id: "1", Value: "Foo"
```

And I update it with a new value:

```
Id: "1", Value: "Bar"
```

My array should read:

```
 0 { Id: "1", Value: "Bar"}
```

Not

```
 0 { Id: "1", Value: "Foo"}
 1 { Id: "1", Value: "Bar"}
```

Example here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cmd1603/y6rgm7z8/67/)

```
 <div id="wrapper">
      <div>
        <input id="1" type="text" value="input_1">
        <button>Button 1</button>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div>
        <input id="2" type="text" value="input_2">
        <button>Button 2</button>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div>
        <input id="3" type="text" value="input_3">
        <button>Button 3</button>
      </div>
      <br>
    </div>
```

jQuery -- will add to the array but not sure how to update if key exists. Looked at other examples but still not getting it

```
   var obj = {
        pairs: []
   }


    $("button").on("click", function() {
      var keyValuePairs = {
          id: "",
          value: ""
      }

      var input_id = $(this).prev().prop('id');
      var dynamic_value = $(this).prev().prop('value');

      if(obj.pairs.length > 0){
        $.each(obj.pairs, function(i, pair) {
          if($(this).id !== input_id){
            obj.pairs.push(keyValuePairs);
            return false;
          } else {
            obj.pairs.splice(i, 1);
            obj.pairs.push(keyValuePairs);
          }
        });
      } else {
          obj.pairs.push(keyValuePairs);
      }

      keyValuePairs.id = input_id;
      keyValuePairs.value = dynamic_value;
      console.log(obj);

   });
```

Comment: Looks like your method is never being called.  Wrap it in a function and call it on 'click' below your keyValuePairs initialization.

Comment: @Adam which method are you referring to? Each input is written to the model on click of it's button child

Comment: I didn't align your { correctly, your JS is being called.  I would remove the space from your id="1 " item just to be safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/y6rgm7z8/93/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var obj = {
    pairs: []
  }

  $("button").on("click", function() {
    var keyValuePairs = {
      id: "",
      value: ""
    }

    var input_id = $(this).prev().prop('id');
    var dynamic_value = $(this).prev().prop('value');

    var pair = obj.pairs.find(item => item.id === input_id)
    if(pair){
      pair.value = dynamic_value;
    } else {
      keyValuePairs.id = input_id;
      keyValuePairs.value = dynamic_value;
      obj.pairs.push(keyValuePairs);
    }

    console.log(obj);

  });


});
```

The find() method executes the function once for each element present in the array:

1. If it finds an array element where the function returns a true value, find() returns the value of that array element (and does not check the remaining values)
2. Otherwise it returns undefined

The find() is better for performance than each().

And we don't need splice() with push() for updating because after find() we have link to the object, so we can change the value.

If find() returns undefined we will push the new object to the array

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) helps to improve the quality of your response. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I finally changed a lot...
I used a flag to know if the update was done...

So I run the `.each()` loop first. It doesn't run if there is no key/pair already. Then a comparison if the change was not yet done, to push a new value.

```js
var obj = {
  pairs: []
}


$("button").on("click", function() {
  var keyValuePairs = {
    id: "",
    value: ""
  }
  var change_done=false;

  var input_id = $(this).prev().prop('id');
  var dynamic_value = $(this).prev().prop('value');

  $.each(obj.pairs, function(i, pair) {
    if(obj.pairs[i].id == input_id){             // Change is here.
      obj.pairs[i].id=input_id;
      obj.pairs[i].value=dynamic_value;
      change_done=true;
      return false;
    }
  });

  if(!change_done || obj.pairs.length == 0){
    obj.pairs.push(keyValuePairs);
  }


  keyValuePairs.id = input_id;
  keyValuePairs.value = dynamic_value;
  console.log(obj);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div>
    <input id="1 "type="text" value="input_1">
    <button>Button 1</button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <input id="2" type="text" value="input_2">
    <button>Button 2</button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <input id="3" type="text" value="input_3">
    <button>Button 3</button>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: I noticed it will update if it is the first index of the array. If not, it will duplicate the id.

Answer (score 2):

See if this helps

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var obj = {
   pairs: []
  }
  
 $("button").on("click", function() {
   var found = false;
   var input_id = $(this).prev().prop('id');
    var dynamic_value = $(this).prev().prop('value');

    var keyValuePairs = {
        id: input_id,
        value: dynamic_value
    }
    
      if(obj.pairs.length > 0){
        $.each(obj.pairs, function(i, pair) {
     if(pair[Object.keys(pair)[0]] === input_id){
           obj.pairs[i] = keyValuePairs;
            found = true;
            return false;
          }
        });
        if(!found)
        obj.pairs.push(keyValuePairs);
      } else {
          obj.pairs.push(keyValuePairs);
      }
      
      console.log(obj);
    
  });
  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>
    <input id="1"type="text" value="input_1">
    <button>Button 1</button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <input id="2" type="text" value="input_2">
    <button>Button 2</button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <input id="3" type="text" value="input_3">
    <button>Button 3</button>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have rewritten a bit. If ID exists, its value will be updated and new row will not be inserted:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var obj = {
      pairs: []
    }

    $("button").on("click", function() {
    var input_id = $(this).prev().prop('id');
    var dynamic_value = $(this).prev().prop('value');
    var isUpdated = false;
    var keyValuePairs = {
        id: input_id,
        value: dynamic_value
    };

    if (obj.pairs.length == 0) {
        obj.pairs.push(keyValuePairs);
        return false;
    }

    $.each(obj.pairs, function(i, pair) {
        if (obj.pairs[i].id === input_id) {
            obj.pairs[i].value = dynamic_value;
            isUpdated = true;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (!isUpdated) {
        obj.pairs.push(keyValuePairs);
    }

    console.log(obj);
  });
});
```

Tested and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
const pair = obj.pairs.find(pair => pair.id === input_id);

if (pair) {
  obj.pairs[input_id] = {...keyValuePairs}
} else {
  obj.pairs.push(keyValuePairs)
}
```

Comment: Wow, not bad. There is a problem with first element but that's because of poor first element insertion from Chris.

Comment: @GytisTenovimas what's a better first element insertion method?

Comment: @ChrisDavila Sorry, perhaps a little poorly worded sentence. It's not poor but looks strange. If you take a look, there is an additional space in your first element's ID: `"1 "`. Because of this, this answer treats as a different index, thus creating 2 elements with ID #1

Comment: @GytisTenovimas got it. I fixed that typo. Thanks for your help.